# Go project and dependencies

Tags: go

I have the following project structure

```
.
├── README.md
├── protos
│   ├── my-proto-output.pb.go
│   └── my-proto.proto
└── grpc-backend
    ├── client
    │   └── client.go
    ├── go.mod
    ├── go.sum
    ├── main.go
    └── a-submodule
```

Inside grpc-backend/main.go I have:

```
package main

import (
  pb "github.com/my-user/my-repo/protos"
  "google.golang.org/api/option"
  "google.golang.org/grpc"
)
```

Inside go.mod I have

```
go 1.13

require (
  google.golang.org/api v0.14.0
  google.golang.org/grpc v1.21.1
)

module github.com/my-user/my-repo/grpc-backend
```

However, when I run `cd grpc-backend && go build` I get

```
go: finding github.com/my-user/my-repo latest
go: finding github.com/my-user/my-repo/protos latest
go: downloading github.com/my-user/my-repo v0.0.0-20200103231607-5a754c449f99
verifying github.com/my-user/my-repo@v0.0.0-20200103231607-5a754c449f99: github.com/my-user/my-repo@v0.0.0-20200103231607-5a754c449f99: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/my-user/my-repo@v0.0.0-20200103231607-5a754c449f99: 410 Gone
```

I don't have any tags like that, I'm in a private repo only commiting to master at the moment.  Furthermore,  proto's are in this same git repo under the package `myrepo`.

Questions:

Did I organize this incorrectly?
Where did that version come from?  It's not in go.sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your module does not include the `protos` package, and thus, the generated grpc source. Move your `go.mod` one level up, and change the module name to `github.com/my-user/my-repo` so the module includes all packages.